# Shopify Inventory_quantity field not updating using shopify API

Tags: php, json, api, shopify

I am trying to update inventory_quantity using Shopify API by Sandeep. My code is below:

```
$variant = array
    (
            "variant"=>array (
                            "id"=>(int) {variant_id},
                            "inventory_quantity"=> (int) 0
            )
    )
);
$senditem = $shopify('POST', '/admin/variants/#{variant_id}.json', 
$variant, $response_headers);
```

The status code is 302, message - Found, but inventory quantity is not resetting.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried changing the POST to PUT, it did not make a difference.

Comment: You have one `)` extra bracket. Delete one from end.

Answer (score 0):

Raj, where you have written above code ? i mean in shopify liquid theme, pages or you are using external pages out of shopify site ?

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the "inventory_management" of that variant is "shopify":

"inventory_management": "shopify"

as is shown in the response in: 'Update the inventory count an existing variant'

http://docs.shopify.com/api/product_variant#update

Answer (score 0):

You are using "POST" method which is used to create product.

Try:

```
$senditem = $shopify('PUT', '/admin/variants/#{variant_id}.json', 
$variant, $response_headers);
```

"PUT" method is used to modify product information.

Take reference: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product-variant